# Animated Dashed Line overlaping image

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

Goal: I would like my dashed line to be drawn across, left to right and the x appear at the end. Also, this dashed line would appear on top of a graphic like this

[image]

I found this example on codepen [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en2xt.jpg): https://codepen.io/Evgeny/pen/IEGoq?editors=1100

I tried adding the path and dash classes on each path but I'm not getting my desired effect. Should this be done with jquery or css?

Here's my codepen
https://codepen.io/drunktuts/pen/aENxXj

The CSS looks like this

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add classes to your svg paths.

Comment: As I see, even if you will add classes there will be no result you expect. I'm not an expert in that case, but I suppose you should check your svg file. Stroked white path with class "dash" should be the highest layer and the green one with class "path" should be behind that. I suppose in that way you will get the result you need

Comment: I think the easiest would be to animate an other path's strokedashoffset, on top of your green one, that would act as a mask https://jsfiddle.net/mqmfj8hv/

Comment: @kalido your codepen link does not work

Comment: weird, when I click on the link the codepen keeps refreshing over and over

Comment: the jsfiddle link works, that looks great kalido! Can I make the background transparent?

Comment: Actually... no... That's the inconvenient. But you could use a real `<mask>` element. https://jsfiddle.net/mqmfj8hv/1/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm going for. So I can overlap this on top of the graphic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't added `.path` class to your svg paths. Have a look at this snippet.

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/dJMBMN)**

```css
.dashed{
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: -1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.target{
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: target 0.5s linear 5s forwards;
}
@keyframes target {
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="500px" height="143px" viewBox="0 0 500 143" enable-background="new 0 0 500 143" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g>
 
    
  <path fill="none" class="path" stroke="#74C044" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M26.565,96.941
   c-1.063,1.702-2.094,3.422-3.107,5.133"/>
    <path fill="none" class="path" stroke="#74C044" stroke-width="6" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
   M427.313,82.577c-17.631,4.149-35.389,7.943-53.32,10.265c-13.979,1.809-28.369,2.609-42.179-0.789
   c-13.539-3.332-25.266-10.732-37.272-17.511c-13.105-7.397-27.067-14.075-42.434-14.208c-16.547-0.145-31.171,7.534-44.262,16.99
   c-12.877,9.301-25.034,21.473-40.702,25.904c-16.987,4.805-34.102-1.76-49.501-8.68c-18.202-8.18-38.376-21.523-59.076-21.017
   c-13.246,0.324-21.792,8.483-28.671,18.342"/>
    <path fill="none" class="dashed" stroke="white" stroke-width="8" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
   M427.313,82.577c-17.631,4.149-35.389,7.943-53.32,10.265c-13.979,1.809-28.369,2.609-42.179-0.789
   c-13.539-3.332-25.266-10.732-37.272-17.511c-13.105-7.397-27.067-14.075-42.434-14.208c-16.547-0.145-31.171,7.534-44.262,16.99
   c-12.877,9.301-25.034,21.473-40.702,25.904c-16.987,4.805-34.102-1.76-49.501-8.68c-18.202-8.18-38.376-21.523-59.076-21.017
   c-13.246,0.324-21.792,8.483-28.671,18.342"/>
    

 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <path fill="none" class="target" stroke="#74C044" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
  M457.573,57.77c0.282,2.831,23.33,30.967,19.774,26.554"/>
 <path fill="none" class="target" stroke="#74C044" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
  M451.367,86.115c4.507-6.301,10.893-11.801,16.509-17.084c4.374-4.116,9.634-7.09,13.991-11.166"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: So, he wants to make dashed one, I just updated your example to add this feature. But it seems dirty, i think we need a clean up the svg: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gorJWw

Comment: wait for a few second and it will load. You need to increase the stroke-width. Please see my updated snippet. Animation kinda weird though.

Comment: That looks pretty good. Any way I can round off the dashes instead of square?

Comment: hmm... There is rule called 'stroke-linecap="round" that suppose to do the job. But won't work in our scenario.